# Image Source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to set an image source in XAML but keep getting "Could not find part of a path..." (plus the directory I want to call). I think I'm messing up what location I'm supposed to be calling. The hierarchy looks something like:

```
-Solution
   -Project
      -Data
      -Images
         -Image_I_want_to_use.png (placeholder name)
      -Themes
         -Demo
           -Default
              -fileImWorkingIn.xaml
              -other files
      -other folders
   -Another Project
   -Third Project
```

How would I configure my image source in XAML so the file I'm working in can utilize the image(s)?

I tried

```
<Image Source="/Project;component/Images/image_to_use.png">
```

(where each name is simply a placeholder) but had no luck. Any pointers? Apologies if this is trivial.

Thanks!

Comment: Ugh I just went through this with silverlight, had to manually load the image as BitmapImage, then set an Image.Source = to that BitmapImage, and then databind that to the viewmodel was a pain

Comment: did you try `<Image Source="Images/image_to_use.png">` with image being built as content

Comment: When you mean image being built as content, you're talking about Build Action under the image's properties, right? If so, I currently have it as a resource. Also, @Pseudo: any good resources for how you did that?

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 4, this `Image.Source` value would work:

```
<Image Source="/AssemblyName;component/FolderName/image_to_use.png">
```

However, Microsoft made some horrible changes in .NET 4.5 that broke many different things and so in .NET 4.5, you'd need to use the full `pack` path like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/image_to_use.png">
```

Answer (score 6):

What fixed it:

```
<Image Source ="pack://application:,,,/Images/image_name.png"></Image>
```

I also changed the Build Action to content.

Thanks for your help everyone!